Why is $[[x \in y]]$ not $y(x)$ in Boolean-valued models?
I'm reading about Boolean-valued models (in order to understand the first Cohen model), and it seems as though the truth value of the formula "$x \in y$", which is written $[[x \in y]]$, is not equal to what it's supposed to be, which is obviously $y(x)$. (In fact, Jech's book gives the inequality $y(x) \le [[x \in y]]$.)
Why is that? Can it be mended?

The issue that leads to defining $\Vert x\in y\Vert$ as something other than just $y(x)$ is the need to make the axiom of extensionality (of set  theory) and the equality axioms (of logic) true in the Boolean-valued model.  (I don't have my copy of Jech's  book handy, so the following will use my favorite notation and conventions; they should be close enough to Jech's.)
The first problem that comes up is extensionality. You could have two functions $y$ and $y'$ that agree on the intersection of their domains and take the value $0$ everywhere else. Then $\Vert y(x)=y'(x)\Vert=1$ for all $x$, so to satisfy the axiom of extensionality we'll need to have $\Vert y=y'\Vert=1$. (We're essentially identifying $y$ with $y'$.)  So truth values of equality statements, like $y=y'$ won't be the obvious "$1$ or $0$ according to whether or not $y$ and $y'$ are the same function."
But now we have a new problem. Consider a function $z$ that maps $y$ to $1$ and everything else (in its domain) to $0$. If we defined truth values of membership statements as you suggest, both $y=y'$ and $y\in z$ would have truth value $1$ while their logical consequence $y'\in z$ would have truth value $0$. In other words, first-order logic would no longer work (i.e., would no longer be sound) for this Boolean-valued model. We'd have to increase $\Vert y'\in z\Vert$ to incorporate the fact that $y'$ "acquires" membership in $z$, not "on its own", but via its equality with $y$.
Of course the problem that I've illustrated with just three elements $y,y',z$ recurs throughout the Boolean-valued model.
But things get even worse. Having modified the truth-values of membership statements, we've messed up extensionality. Consider, for example, a function $z'$ that maps $y'$to $1$ and everything else (in its domain) to $0$. Analogously to the preceding paragraph, $z'$ has $y'$ as  a member directly and has $y$ as a member indirectly via $y=y'$. So now $z$ and $z'$ have the same  members, and extensionality requires $\Vert z=z'\Vert=1$.
And so forth. Every time we adjust truth values for $=$, we have to adjust truth values for $\in$ to get logic to work properly. Every time we adjust truth values for $\in$, we have to adjust truth values for $=$ to get extensionality.
This looks like a vicious circle, but it turns out to be a recursion, so it makes sense. The key idea for making it a recursion is that, whenever a change A forces us to make another change B, the rank of B is lower than the rank of A. Here the "rank" of an equality or membership statement depends on the set-theoretic ranks of the two elements involved and on whether it's an $=$ or an $\in$ statement. I'll leave it as a nice exercise (unless Jech already did it for you) to find the right notion of rank to make the recursion work.
In the end, the complicated definitions of $\Vert x=y\Vert$ and $\Vert x\in y\Vert$ amount to writing out this recursion explicitly. They are the minimal modifications of the naive definitions to make extensionality and equality axioms hold. Note also that these definitions look like extensionality and equality axioms except that they have $y(x)$ in a few places where I'd expect $\Vert x\in y\Vert$.
(In the preceding paragraph, I wrote "complicated definitions", but it's really just one interlocked definition, which simultaneously defines truth value for both $=$ and $\in$; the two depend on each other as explained above.)

A priori one would probably be drawn towards trying to define sets as functions on an entire universe that has previously been constructed. But then the theory wouldn't be self-contained, so perhaps one could just extend all functions to zero somehow.

And the notion of recursion is in the Jech, he chooses the lexicographical well-ordering of On².

Another issue: suppose for example you use ${ 0, 1 }^2$ as $B$ (so $V^B$ essentially amounts to $V \times V$), and define $y$ with some singleton domain ${ x }$ and value $(1, 0)$.  Then you would want $\lVert y = \emptyset \rVert$ to be $(0, 1)$ because the pair of sets corresponding to $y$ should be $({ x_1 }, \emptyset)$ where $(x_1, x_2)$ is the pair of sets corresponding to $x$.

I agree with your assignment of $|y = \emptyset|$, even though I would assign $({x}, \emptyset)$ to $y$.

Since the definition of the identity does not need itself at a lower level of the induction, but only relies on $\in$, I will now try to extend the functions and prove the inference rules and ZFC.

In Jech's book, he somehow puts all variables into the structure itself.

By the way, inference seems to work.

@Cloudscape "Since the definition of the identity does not need itself at a lower level of the induction, but only relies on $\in$...": But then the definition of $\in$ in turn needs instances of the identity at lower levels (which in turn needs instances of $\in$ at yet lower levels, which needs instances of identity at even lower levels, etc.).

@DanielSchepler I mean for the alternative, direct definition of $\in$ as $x \in y := y(x)$.

"And the notion of recursion is in Jech, he chooses the lexicographical well-ordering of $Ord^2$."  I suppose then the recursion is by $(\min { \operatorname{rank}(x), \operatorname{rank}(y) }, \max { \operatorname{rank}(x), \operatorname{rank}(y) })$?  Something like that would be needed to account for the fact that the recursion on $\lVert x=y \rVert = \lVert x \subseteq y \rVert \cdot \lVert y \subseteq x \rVert$ swaps the roles of $y$ and $x$, I think.

If $z$ is in the domain of $x$, say, then the rank of $z$ is at least one lower than that of $x$. Thus, (rank($x$), rank($y$)) seems to be sufficient, at least in order to get SOME definition, which is also symmetric. But I didn't calculate the entire proof yet, for I was hoping to find a shortcut.

OK, I think I now see your point. We have to assume that the previous notions are defined for both orders (x, y) and (y, x), and then we can do the induction over the lexicographical order.

So, I first want to thank everyone for very helpful and inspiring suggestions (even though I very emphatically reject the notion of any genetical inferiority on my part).
I think I've now got some sort of definition that works (even though I'll have to check that over the next few days). The construction process is akin to the stages of ordinary set theory.
We start with the empty set, and define $[[\emptyset \in \emptyset]] := 0$ and $[[\emptyset = \emptyset]] = 1$.
The induction step is done by taking all functions
$x \mapsto [[x \in y]]$ such that the equation
$$
[[x \in y]] = \sum_{z \text{ from previous steps}} [[z \in y]][[z = x]]
$$
is valid. Then for at least one of $x, y$ in the current step, we define
$$
[[x = y]] := \prod_{z \text{ from previous steps}} ([[z \in x]] \Leftrightarrow [[z \in y]]),
$$
and then extend the definition of $[[ \in ]]$ to where an element of the current stage occurs on the left (by the formula above).
I do hope this does the trick, but only the rigorous checking of all the statements will show it (for instance, in my reference the substitution rule for formulas was rather at the end, and thus I didn't check it the last time).

If I understand your proposal correctly, that model doesn't satisfy the pairing axiom - for instance, if you're doing a forcing to add a new subset $S$ of $\omega$ to the model, then the forcing model should also contain ${ S }$, but that set is indistinguishable from empty set in terms of class functions on the "original" universe.

Right, we don't seem to have enough functions there.

@DanielSchepler I just tried to fix it. Pairing should work now.

What about the issue of needing to satisfy the substitution principle that Andreas Blass's answer brought up?  For instance, you would want $\lVert x \in z \rVert \cdot \lVert x = y \rVert \le \lVert y \in z \rVert$ for all $x,y,z$ in the model.  (You might be able to get partway there by requiring the class functions to be "well defined" in this sense -- but then it would seem to be impossible for any such class function to have a set-sized support for most $B$ of interest.)

@spaceisdarkgreen DanielSchepler has raised a valid objection against the direct definition. But my objection to the standard definition is that both x(y) and $|y \in x|$ are supposed to be values for containment.

@spaceisdarkgreen I took "the equivalence is taken inside $B$" just to mean $p \Leftrightarrow q$ is defined to be $p\cdot q + (\lnot p) \cdot (\lnot q)$ calculated using the Boolean algebra operations.  (And then, a sample property that this satisfies is: $p \le (q \Leftrightarrow r)$ if and only if $p\cdot q = p\cdot r$.)

@DanielSchepler Yeah, I'm not thinking straight, thanks, deleting

@Cloudscape It might be more useful to think of an element $x$ of $V^B$ as a specification for generating a set in the boolean-valued model of ZFC -- it's the "minimal" set such that $x(u) \le \lVert u \in x \rVert$ for all $u \in \operatorname{dom}(x)$, given that the model must satisfy extensionality and substitution.

@DanielSchepler Well, I tried, but sometimes you're lucky, and sometimes you aren't.
